# Offset Camera to Local Axis

Tags: camera, constraints

I have a road with a plane locked to it through a curve and a constraint. I also have a camera that's locked to the plane with a *Copy Rotation* and a *Copy Location* constraint. However, when I enter the camera view, the camera goes inside the road, meaning I need to move it up. However, when I move it up (Z axis) and the camera approaches a bank turn, the camera goes way off the screen. So what I need to do is move it on the *local* Z axis. I've tried using the *Limit Location* constraint, but even when I set it to *Local Space*, I still have difficulties trying to get it to move on the local Z axis. Is there a way I can offset the camera so that it doesn't have this problem? Here's a picture representation:

[image]

Thanks in advance if you can help!
Here's the .blend file:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can offset the ***origin*** of the plane using (for instance) the 3D cursor.  I placed the cursor above the plane and used ***Alt+Ctrl+shift+C*** then chose "**Origin to 3D Cursor**".  That means that the plane's origin is now above it, so the camera is now locked to the new origin through the constraint.

[image][image]

Comment: That seemed to work! Thank you so much, it helps a lot!

Comment: @Grant I would also add another plane (or an _empty_) to go in front of the one linked to the camera.  You could have the camera point toward that plane's origin.  So if you went around a corner or crested a hill, the camera would always be "looking ahead".

Comment: Alright, I'll go ahead and try that, it seems like a great idea!